# Calling javascript __dopostback function, from C# in windows application

Tags: c#, javascript

I want to call "__dopostback" function, in my c# program, in my program I want to read a web page content. But in the main web page, the links that I want to read their content are called by __dopostback, function in javascript, for example the function that page call when I click on the button is:

```
javascript:__doPostBack(ctl00$MainContent$GridView1,Page$2)
```

Now, how I can call this function from my c# program, note that my program is a windows application not an asp.net application!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any way to do this, may be you can use Web Request.

http://dotnet-codeguru.blogspot.com/2010/02/send-http-web-request-using-c.html